# Run a React Native app without launching Xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, react-native

Can an `iOS` app (built entirely with `React Native`) be built/run from the command line? `PhoneGap` has a nice [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) utility for doing just that, but I haven't had any luck with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you build the project once using Xcode, then you can close it, run `npm start` in your project root (to start the packager), fire up the Simulator (maybe using ios-sim). Since you built it once in Xcode, the app will be installed in the simulator so you can just run it and the whole CMD+R refresh process will work.

Comment: This is a great tip for running it, but what about rebuilding it? I'd rather not have to fire up XCode. Especially for a demo. I like the idea of saying "npm install -g react-native-cli" then "react-native init HelloWorld" then "react-native run -iOSSimulator" or something, you know? This exists in tons of other frameworks.

Personally? I'm guessing that it's just a matter of time and Facebook will make it happen.

Comment: You can probably use xcodebuild for that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-HOW_DO_I_BUILD_MY_PROJECTS_FROM_THE_COMMAND_LINE_

Answer (score 2):

Fire up the server with:

```
$ npm start
```

Build/run the app in the ios simulator:

```
$ react-native run-ios
```